# Laravel login once and be loggined in in multiple subdomains

Tags: php, laravel, apache, authentication

our website is created with laravel 7 on an apache server.
we have an app that has 3 different subdomains. for example:

```
mainwebsite.com

products.mainwebsite.com

customers.mainwebsites.com

suppliers.mainwebsite.com
```

the subdomains have been set this way :

```
Route::domain('supplier.mainwebsite.com')->group(function () {
      Route::get('/dashboard', 'ExampleController@show')->name('example-show')->middleware('auth','isActive','role:supplier|admin|producer');
});
```

we use spatie permission package to check the roles.

now the problem here is with authentication. if user is logged in to suppliers.mainwebsite.com, when they go to mainwebsite.com they should login again. we want them to be logged in in all the subdomains. because some of the pages are similar but show different content based on user's role. for example dashboard is in mainwebsite.com/dashboard but if you have logged in to suppliers.mainwebsite and there is a link to go to dashboard which goes to mainwebsite.com.dashboard because the subdomain is different they should login again. we want them to stay logged in.

I appreciate your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

in `config/session.php`

```php
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

to

```php
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.mainwebsite.com'),
```

---

or in .env

```json
SESSION_DOMAIN='.mainwebsite.com',
```

Comment: My goooooood you are unbelievable. Thanks for you're answer. I miss you 

Comment: No, this is working for subdomain but not for domain.

Comment: @DeepakPanwar for multiple domain session and cookies are not shared as per security reason but you can connect same database and can login via code